# ¿Cómo le puedo cambiar el color a mi hr con css?

Tags: css, html5, selectores-css

resulta que hace poco comence a hacer una web de postres, y en la descripcion de la tarjeta queria poner un `Hr` para diferenciar el titulo de la descripcion.

en mi HTML solo tengo el `hr` sin clases y en mi CSS no se que poner para poder cambiarlo de color

//despues de probar las respuestas

me di cuenta que me faltaba declarar el ancho de el `Hr` y por eso no me mostraba los resultados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues, como cualquier otro elemento html:

```css
hr {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Te recomiendo que te leas algún tutorial de HTML y CSS básico: https://www.ciudadano2cero.com/aprender-css-basico-desde-cero/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pon en tu archivo css...

```
hr { color: elcolor; }
```

El color lo puedes poner en ingles, aunque te recomiendo usar https://htmlcolorcodes.com/es/selector-de-color/ ahí sacar el color que quieras y lo pones así...

```
hr { color: #FF5733; }
```

Revisa también https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/ vienen todo bien explicadito